# How to add default pagination to this code?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have this code to get the latest 3 posts from "novels" category and display the content inside html tags.

```
<? $novels = get_option('of_novels') ?>
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; query_posts('category_name=$novels&posts_per_page=3'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="sliderunit">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <div class="novelsslidertitle">
            <div class="arrow-left"></div>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img class="cross" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/cross.png"/></a>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <h3>رواية</h3>
        </div>
    </div>                    
<?php endwhile;?>
```

What I need to know is how to add default next post in wordpress to this code?

Comment: Do you want the next button to display the next 3 posts?

Comment: yes, exactly.. Default next and previous

Comment: It's not going to be straight forward, you will need to get some information from Wordpress, such as the total number of posts. Maybe start by looking here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts Once you have the total posts you have to generate the new URL you need to append to the anchor links and adjust the 'paged' variable on the URL.
Is there no pagination which comes as part of your WP template?

Comment: no I am not using a template. I built my theme from scratch and I dun have a pagination inside my template

Comment: @user2203146 building pagination is simple but for starters please dont use `query_posts` use `WP_Query` instead..

Comment: any details or links to something I can read?